# Streamlit can't play .mp4 using cv.2 videocapture()

Tags: python, opencv, streamlit, mediapipe

After comparing the similarity between the two by recognizing the hand movements of benchmark_viedo and user_video (webcam or designated video) using mediapipe, I want to output the result in streamlit, but if streamlit_app.py is executed, the .mp4 file does not play and only an empty screen is output.
The code of streamlit_app.py is as follows.

```
import cv2, time
import pose_module as pm
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
from fastdtw import fastdtw
import streamlit as st

st.title('Dance Comparison')

st.button("Clear", type="primary")

option = st.radio(label='video', options=['Example', 'Try Yourself'])

placeholder = st.columns(2, gap="small")

col1 = placeholder[0].empty()
col2 = placeholder[0].empty()

def countdown():
    for sec in range(3,0,-1):
        col1.metric(label='video', value=sec)
time.sleep(1)

def restart():
    st.session_state.page = 0

if st.button("Start"):

    countdown()

    benchmark_video = 'dance_videos/benchmark_dance.mp4'
    
    if option == 'Example':
        user_video = 'dance_videos/right_dance.mp4'
    else:
        user_video = 0

    col1.subheader("Benchmark")
    col2.subheader("User")

    benchmark_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(benchmark_video)
    user_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

    fps_time = 0 #Initializing fps to 0

    detector_1 = pm.poseDetector()
    detector_2 = pm.poseDetector()
    frame_counter = 0
    correct_frames = 0

    while (benchmark_cam.isOpened() or user_cam.isOpened()):
        try:
            ret_val, image_1 = benchmark_cam.read()
            #Loop the video if it ended. If the last frame is reached, reset the capture and the frame_counter
            if frame_counter == benchmark_cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
                frame_counter = 0 #Or whatever as long as it is the same as next line
                correct_frames = 0
                benchmark_cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

            # image_1 = cv2.resize(image_1, (720,640))
            image_1 = detector_1.findHands(image_1)
            lmList_user = detector_1.findPosition(image_1)
            del lmList_user[1:11]

            ret_val_1,image_2 = user_cam.read()
            #Loop the video if it ended. If the last frame is reached, reset the capture and the frame_counter
            if frame_counter == user_cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
                frame_counter = 0 #Or whatever as long as it is the same as next line
                correct_frames = 0
                user_cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

            # image_2 = cv2.resize(image_2, (720,640))
            image_2 = detector_2.findHands(image_2)
            lmList_benchmark = detector_2.findPosition(image_2)
            del lmList_benchmark[1:11]

            frame_counter += 1


            if ret_val_1 or ret_val:
                error, _ = fastdtw(lmList_user, lmList_benchmark, dist=cosine)

                # Displaying the error percentage
                cv2.putText(image_2, 'Error: {}%'.format(str(round(100*(float(error)),2))), (10, 30),
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

                # If the similarity is > 90%, take it as correct step. Otherwise incorrect step.
                if error < 0.3:
                    cv2.putText(image_2, "CORRECT STEPS", (40, 600),
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    correct_frames += 1
                else:
                    cv2.putText(image_2,  "INCORRECT STEPS", (40, 600),
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(image_2, "FPS: %f" % (1.0 / (time.time() - fps_time)), (10, 50),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

                # Display the dynamic accuracy of dance as the percentage of frames that appear as correct
                if frame_counter==0:
                    frame_counter = user_cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
                cv2.putText(image_2, "Dance Steps Accurately Done: {}%".format(str(round(100*correct_frames/frame_counter, 2))), (10, 70), 
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 255), 2)
                
                # Display both the benchmark and the user videos
                col1.image(image_1, use_column_width=True)
                col2.image(image_2, use_column_width=True)

                fps_time = time.time()
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
            else:
                break
        except:
            pass

    benchmark_cam.release()
    user_cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In this code, the image is read in units of frames, and the similarity of hand movements between the two images is compared and played in units of frames in streamlit. The execution result of streamlit_app.py is as shown in the following image.
It was confirmed that the findHands and findPosition used in streamlit_app.py work normally.
How do I fix the code to solve this problem?